Add specific log in Docker Container
I have a Java Application (Jboss server) and in the currently VM architecture I have a audit.log configured with log4j
  <appender name="AUDIT" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/audit.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

Now, I have containerized the application in Docker, but the logs were concatenated and displayed in the Docker Output Log.
Is there any way to keep the separate audit.log file in Docker?
The goal is to put this in a k8s cluster > read the log with FluentD > connect it to ElasticSearch.
Thank you!
